# how to mix variables and loop indexes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I got ten javascript variables named
street1, street2, street3 ... street10.

I have to do a loop by putting into these variables.
so I did:

```
var data;
for (var i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
data = data + 'this is street '+street+i+'\n';
}
```

console log prints "street" does not exist...which is right because my variable is named street1.
there's a way I can "mix" variables and index?

Comment: **Why** don't you use an array?

Comment: so there isn't a solution? if so i'll convert in an array.

Comment: Not to be rude, but arrays should really be the first thing to try when doing things like this, it's what they were made for.

Comment: yeah, i know, i wantedd to know if there is such method...nevermind,for now on, always using arrays!

Comment: @Marco: There is such a method - as a few answers have highlighted. Array's are the more common way of handling it, but it's still perfectly dooable.

Comment: yes, and its square bracket notation...but i prefere old good arrays :D thanks Ian!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generally accepted way to do this is using [arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp). Your code would look something like this:

```
var streets = ["Park street", "First street", "Pine street", "Rainbow road", "Yellow brick road", "View street", "Ninth street", "Cedar street", "Lake court", "Hill street"];

for(var i = 0; i < streets.length; i++) {
    data += "this is street " + streets[i] + "\n";
}
```

The key improvement is that it will auto-adjust to however many streets are in the array due to the `i < streets.length` part of the for loop.

You *could* do it with `eval()`, but besides it being inefficient and more trouble than it's worth, that can be dangerous.

Comment: thanks. I'll use an array instead. your code is minimal and elegant.

Answer (score 3):

It would make more sense to store this item in an array:

```
var items = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   Console.log(items[i]);
}
```

Alternatively you can use square bracket notation. Accessing `Street1` will depend on where it lives, assuming you've not scoped anything the following will get you the value, depending on where `street1` is defined:

```
this['street' + i]
window['street' + i]
```

Comment: using square bracket returns same error in console log...if there isn't a solution i'll have to use an array..

Comment: @Marco: If you could set up a quick JSFiddle I'll fix it for you - it's most likely down to where you've defined `street1` which isnt' clear from your question.

Comment: @Marco It depends where `street1` is defined. You may need to use `window`, or define your variable explicitly

Answer (score 3):

You really should use an array for this:

```
var street = [];
street.push("Fake St");
for(var i=0; i<street.length; i++) {
    data += "this is street: " + street[i] + "\n";
}
```

But you *can* achieve your original idea using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
var data;
for (var i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
data = data + 'this is street '+ this["street"+i] +'\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use `eval` to do this, but it's slow, dangerous, and just all-around bad practice, so i'm not going to show you.

What you can do instead is to use an array.

```
var streets = ['street1','street2','etc.','street10'];
```

Then, you can loop through the array and get the values:

```
var data;
for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
data = data + 'this is street '+streets[i]+'\n';
}
```

Comment: yes, in the end i have to use an array. i know eval vould be too risky. thanks.